# Notice (8): Undefined property:

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Please help me with this:
am I missing something?

I am getting following error:

Notice (8): Undefined property: Property::$Project [APP\controllers\properties_controller.php, line 614]

// This is code where warning occurs

```
$projects = $this->Property->Project->find('list');
```

**and in project.php (model file)**

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Property' => array(
        'className' => 'Property',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in property.php `var $belongsTo = 'Project'`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write in properties_controller.php

```
var $uses = array('Project');
```

then you use

```
$projects = $this->Project->find('list');
```

Also add in  property.php

```
var $belongsTo = 'Project';
```

Comment: The best solution is to ensure Property belongsTo Project as @TuteC says, then the true relationship is defined and the find will work as intended.